# Get sum of the cells nearby (right of) all found values on the sheet

Tags: google-sheets

[image]I have the sheet with much of dropdowns (identical).
I need the formula to get sum of all cells located right of selected dropdowns.
For every dropdown value.

```
I.e.
Dropdown: 1/11 estel, 4/6 estel, 5/00 estel.
I select the 1/11 estel in 3 dd's on the sheet, 4/6 and 5/00 - 1 times.
I need:
Sum of all cells right of '1/11 estel' values selected.
e.t.c
```

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of your sheet would help? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @JulienPerrenoud added

Comment: @I'-'I 70 for '1/11 estel'

Comment: Think it must be something like =ARRAYFORMULA(sum(IF(OR(left(A1:Z1000)="1/11 estel"),VALUE(RIGHT_CELL_ADDRESS),0)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the table shown below is A1:F20,
[image]

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(A1:F20=A1,B1:G20))
```

- IF to shift the array one column right and apply the constraining condition
- SUMPRODUCT to sum up the  resulting array